# Find для string

Tags: c++

Подскажите, что в этом коде выполняет эта строчка `cout<<(i->find("r")==-1`. Результат на экране 100 не очень понятен, так как у нас в каждом слове есть символ 'r'.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    set<string>ss;
    ss.insert("Petrov");
    ss.insert("Borov");
    ss.insert("Abzalov");
    ss.insert("Borov");
    for(set<string>::iterator i= ss.begin();i!= ss.end();++i)
        cout<<(i->find("r")==-1);
    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то (i->find("r")==-1) должно вернуть булево значение true или false. Зачем такая конструкция нужна, я не понимаю. И возращает она не 100, а числа 1 0 0. Т.е. в первом имени нет буквы (r), а в остальных есть.

Comment: Да как же, в "Petrov" есть буква r.

Comment: @Роман Пономаренко, если Вы хотите увидеть 1, если в слове есть "r", то надо написать не `==`, а `!=`.

Comment: @Роман Пономаренко вы используете контейнер типа set, и первое имя в нем будет Abzalov, затем Borov, затем Petrov, и всё, всего три неповторяющихся имени. В контейнере типа set дубликаты удаляются.